# Laravel php artisan make:auth no migration table is created

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am following Laravel documentation for creating [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) system.

### My Steps Are

1. Installing fresh laravel using `laravel new my-project`
2. Then enter into directory (`cd my-project`). Edit the database config file with database credentials.
3. Then run `php artisan make:auth`. All migration php files are created.
4. Run `php artisan migrate`. CLI responds with `nothing to migrate`

So I went back to check the database using phpmyadmin. I do not see any migration table.

### System & Version info

1. Vagrant box `laravel/homestead`
2. Database mariaDb
3. Laravel installer `v1.3.5`, by cli command `laravel -v`
4. Laravel `v5.4.16`, from `composer.lock`

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: I did, check my step 4. I also tried `php artisan migrate:refresh` but no use.

Comment: did you specify your DB name in `.env` file?

Comment: set "database name,user name,password" in .env  file and config/database.php

Comment: It could be because of the dash in your project name, take a look at [this](https://laravel.io/forum/08-10-2014-nothing-to-migrate)

Comment: @BalrajAllam Thank you for your comment. Indeed I missed the `.env` file. I thought `config/database.php` file is the place I should place DB credentials. If you post an answer I will accept it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: @Learner Yes, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your database in `.env` file

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=DbName   //Your DB Name 
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password123
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can try this:

`php artisan migrate:install` which creates the migrations table only

`php artisan migrate` runs your other migrations